# cisco 2911/k9 pptp server limit clients

Tags: cisco, pptp

1. How to view, how much clients can connect to 2911/k9 by vpdn(pptp) at same time?
2. Which ios is need to enable mppe on 2911/k9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be any "hardcoded" limit to the maximum number of clients in IOS. However, several things may limit you:

- Number of [IDB (Interface Descriptor Block)](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/iosswrel/ps1835/products_tech_note09186a0080094322.shtml) used.
- Number IP address in the vpdn pool.
- Possible license limits. I don't have any ISR-G2 on hand, but [this document](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/routers/ps10536/qa_c67_606268.pdf) shows that there is a maximum of 225 tunnels (IPSec or SSL, no mention of pptp) with a SEC-K9 license.

Regarding the IOS, 2911 will use universal images, so MPPE should be included. You can verify with the [feature navigator](http://www.cisco.com/go/fn).

Pay attention to the licensing as it seems that this will be your limitations.